# gobwas/ws Send opPing over net.Conn

Tags: go, websocket, gobwas-ws

Can somebody help me understand what am I doing wrong here, all I'm trying to do is write a Ping message over a net.Conn instance (`server`), and reply back with a Pong which is expected on a net.Conn instance (`client`).

I have annotated the code with some errors that I receive.

```
reader.go
func read(conn net.Conn) {
  for {
        conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second))
        _, op, err := wsutil.ReadClientData(conn)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("wsmanager read: %v", err) // read: write pipe: deadline exceeded
            return
        }
        if op != ws.OpPing {
          continue
        }

        c.conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(3 * time.Second))
        if err = wsutil.WriteServerMessage(c.conn, ws.OpPong, []byte{}); err != nil {
            log.Printf("wsmanager: send pong error: %v", err)
            return
        }
  }
}

// reader_test.go

     client, server := net.Pipe()
     go read(server) // starts the loop above
     err := wsutil.WriteClientMessage(server, ws.OpPing, []byte{})
     if err != nil {
       t.Fatalf("failed sending pings message %v", err)
     }
     _, op, err := wsutil.ReadServerData(client)
     if err != nil {
         t.Errorf("exp no err, got %v", err)
     }
     if op != ws.OpPong {
       t.Errorf("exp ws.OpPong, got %v", op)
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for using this library :)
As the doc states, the ReadData functions read *data* from the connection; that is, application specific data, not the control messages. Control frames are handled implicitly in these functions. If you want to read any kind of message, you could use wsutil.Reader or the plain ws.Read functions.

https://godoc.org/github.com/gobwas/ws/wsutil#ReadClientData

Comment: thanks, I realised that around the time you left your comment, I ended up using `wsutil.ReadClientMessage`, with `wsutil.HandleClientControlMessage` and handle OpPong differently as I want to extend the ReadDeadline